# Add volume for each strimzi kafka broker

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, strimzi

I have currently 3 brokers and 3 zookeepers that were created using the strimzi k8s operator but i need 3 volumes seperated for each broker, how can i achieve this?

Comment: Do you want 3 volumes ... one for each Kafka broker? Or 3 volumes for each broker? The solution from fvaleri is for the second case. For the first case you can do the same but with only one volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JBOD storage type](https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/0.21.1/using.html#ref-jbod-storage-str) in your CR definition. This is one approach to providing increased data storage for Kafka brokers. It can also improve performance. Note that this is supported only for Kafka, not for Zookeeper.

```yaml
spec:
  kafka:
    storage:
      type: jbod
      volumes:
      - id: 0
        type: persistent-claim
        size: 10Gi
        deleteClaim: false
      - id: 1
        type: persistent-claim
        size: 10Gi
        deleteClaim: false
      - id: 2
        type: persistent-claim
        size: 10Gi
        deleteClaim: false
```